# 'The executable 'modinfo' not found in the PATH variable' error while trying to run vagrant up

Tags: laravel, symfony, vagrant, homestead

After installing my project files on my homestead box I ran `vagrant reload` and got:

> The executable 'modinfo' Vagrant is trying to run was not
>   found in the PATH variable.
>   This is an error.
>   Please verify this software is installed and on the path.

Now I can't run Vagrant anymore due to this error.

Comment: Well, is it installed? Should be the package `kmod`, but that obviously depends on your system. You need to check your http server's PATH variable too, obviously.

Comment: Even tho I didn't quite get your comment, it is installed. It's not set in the $PATH variable though. It was working before but now it isn't.

Comment: I think you're trying to run vagrant inside of the virtual box which is not possible, exit first and then run `vagrant reload --provision`

Comment: Under which path is the executable installed, is it executable for the http server process and what is the content of the `PATH` environment variable of that process?